# How is float to int type conversion done in C?

Tags: c, types, casting

```
float a = 1000.1;  
int b = (int)a;  // how is this done?
```

Can anyone explain the bit level operations for converting a floating point to an integer?

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20302904/converting-int-to-float-or-float-to-int-using-bitwise-operations-software-float